Use strong induction to prove that $12\mid n^4-n^2$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$

This question is similar to this question, but they are not the same, so please don't mark it as duplicate.

I am currently reading the Book of proof. There's an example problem on page 188, illustrating the method called Strong induction. The outline for proof by strong induction as follows:

Proposition The statements $S_{1}, S_{2}, S_{3}, S_{4}$,... are all true.
Proof. (Strong induction)
(1) Prove the first statement $S_{1}$. (Or the first several $S_{n}$, if needed.)
(2) Given any integer $k\ge{1}$, prove ($S_{1}\land S_{2}\land S_{3}\land S_{k})\implies S_{k+1}$.

The main difference between strong induction and normal mathematical induction is that is not only uses the item $S_{k}$ to prove that $S_{k+1}$, but it also uses the previous $m$ items ($m\le{k}$).
Then he uses strong induction to prove that $12\mid n^4-n^2$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
The proof as follows:

Say $S_{n}: 12\mid n^4-n^2$
He prove that $S_{n}$ is true for $S_{1}$ to $S_{6}$
for $k\ge{6}$, assume $12\mid m^4-m^2$ for $1\le{m}\le{k}$.($S_{1}...S_{k}$ is true). We want to infer from $12\mid (k-5)^4-(k-5)^2$ to $12\mid (k+1)^4-(k+1)^2$. He set $k-5=l$ and $l^4-l^2=12a$，then $k+1=l+6$. Substitute $l+6$ into the $(k+1)^4-(k+1)^2$, and he finally reach $12(a+2l^3+18l^2+71l+105)$, successfully prove the proposition.

For the proof, he just said that:

In particular, if $S_{1}$ through $S_{k}$ are true, then $S_{k-5}$ is true, provided $k-5\ge{1}$. We will show $S_{k-5}\implies S_{k+1}$ instead of $S_{k}\implies S_{k+1}$. But as $k-5\ge{1}$, we have $k\ge{6}$. Then our basic steps must check that $S_{1}$ to $S_{6}$ are all true.

My question is: Why does he choose to use the first 6 items as the base to prove the following proposition. In other words, why choosing $S_{k-5}\implies S_{k+1}$ instead of $S_{k-2}\implies S_{k+1}$. I tried it, but failed with some coefficients not a multiple of 12. Are there any internal mathematical theorem here?
I don't know how to deal with the problem when I first came across this, and I saw him choosing the first 6 items as a group, and finally reached the conclusion that $n^4-n^2$ is a multiple of 12. His inference just looks like magic! I wonder if it comes from purely mathematical intuition or some intrinsic number theory theorem. There's no illustration on how he came across this idea from the textbook, so I am reaching out for help here.

I think you keep using $\nmid$ when you mean $\mid$ (\mid). Edit: ah, @JohnOmielan beat me to it.

Sorry, I fix the latex notation. It's correct now,

Duplicate notice: please don't post alternative solution methods as answers  since they will almost surely be duplicates.

Here $\:\!\color{#0af}6\:\!$ is chosen because it is some period of $\,S_n\bmod \color{#c00}{12},\,$ i.e. $\,\color{#c00}{S_{n+\color{#0af}6}\equiv S_n\pmod{\!4\cdot 3}},\,$ because $\:\!\color{#0af}6\:\!$ is common multiple of some periods $(\color{#0af}{2}\,$ and $\,\color{#0af}3)$ of $\,S_n\,$ taken $\!\bmod \color{#c00}4\,$ and $\! \bmod \color{#c00}3,\,$ resp.
Thus we can employ the following "$\!\!\bmod\color{#0af}6$" induction schema:
Lemma $\ $ If $\,\color{#00f}{S_1,S_2,\ldots S_{\:\!\color{#0af}6}}\,$ are true, and for all $\,k\!:\, \color{#c00}{S_k\Rightarrow S_{k+\color{#0af}6}}$ then $\,S_n\,$ is true for all $\,n\ge 1$.
Proof $\, $  (Base Cases) $ $ If $\,\color{#00f}{n\le \color{#0af}6}\,$ then $\,\color{#00f}{S_n}\,$ is true by hypothesis. (Induction Step) suppose $\,\color{#00f}n>\color{#0af}6\,$ and suppose for complete induction that $\,S_k\,$ is true for all $\,k < n.\,$ In particular $S_{n-\color{#0aaf}6}$ is true, which by $\rm\color{#c00}{hypothesis}$ implies that $S_n$ is true, so the claim follows by complete induction.
Remark $ $ Essentially the inductive step lifts the truth from any "remainder" index $\,k\le 6\,$ up to all naturals $\,n\equiv k\pmod{\!6},\,$ ie $\,k\to k+6\to k+12\to \cdots\,$ It reaches every natural because every natural $\,n\,$ is congruent to its remainder  $\,k = n\bmod_+\! 6 \,\le\, 6,\,$ so the inductive lifting of truth from $\,k\,$ eventually reaches $\,n = k + 6j.\,$ Essentially the induction is "piggybacking" on the inductive proof of the division algorithm (here division by $\,6)$.

Actually $,S_n\equiv 0\pmod{!4},$ has period $1,,$ so we could instead use $,S_{n+3}\equiv S_n,$ and base cases $,S_1,S_2,S_3.\ \ $

See here for another example of such modular induction. $\ \ $

I find myself lack of some knowledge on elementary number theory at this time. May be I should go and read some textbooks on elementary number theory before continuing on reading this book? Sometimes when I am struggling with the exercises on , there are many exercises and proof that require knowledge about modular arithmetic and number theory theorems, which I haven't learned yet. Thank you for your answer! It's really clear to me!

@Gwen There are in fact more refined number-theoretical methods for exploiting such modular periodicity of powers (e.g. mod order reduction). However such added complexity only serves to obfuscate the sought goal of illustrating the method of strong induction.  For such, the author should have chosen a simpler example, e.g. here and here. $\ \ $

He presents an example - any coins greater or equal to 8 cents could be combined by a multiple of 3 cents and 5 cents, just like the link you just posted. I understand the proof of that problem, but the modular period is not so explicit in this problem. Thank you for your advice!

Excuse me, but I am a little confused. I search for some references on Euler's theorem, modular exponential, the calculation of the order of a mod n, addition chaining algorithm. But I still confused how to calculate the period here. Can you tell me why factoring 12 into $4 \cdot 3$ instead of $2 \cdot 6$ or $1 \cdot 12$? And why choose the common multiple of the 2 modulo results? You said that $6$ is a common multiple of $a \mod 4$ period and $a \mod 3$ period, but what is the a here? Are there any relationships between a and 6?

@Gwen $!\bmod \color{#c00}3,$ it repeats every $\color{#0af}3$ terms: $,S_{\large n+\color{#0af}3}\equiv S_{n}\pmod{!\color{#c00}3},,$ so it also repeats every $\color{darkorange}6$ terms, $9$ terms,$\ldots,\color{#0af}3j$ terms. Similarly $!\bmod \color{#c00}4$ it repeats every $\color{#0af}2$ terms, so also every $4$ terms, $\color{darkorange}6$ terms, $\ldots,\color{#0af}2k$ terms.

So both $!\bmod \color{#c00}{3\ &\ 4}$ it repeats every $\color{darkorange}6=\color{#0af}{3\cdot 2}$ terms, so ditto $!\bmod\color{#c00}{12 = 3\cdot 4},,$ i.e.  $,\color{#c00}{3,4}\mid S_{\large n+\color{darkorange}6}-S_n \Rightarrow \color{#c00}{3\cdot 4}\mid S_{\large n+\color{darkorange}6}-S_n\ \ $
